# according to my error report a syntax error has occurred

Tags: php

The error reported:

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' on line number 3

My code is below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
     $id = $_SESSON['id'];
     $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM * users WHERE id = :id";
     $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
     $statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
     while($rs  = $statement->fetch()){
          $username = $rs['username'];
          $email = $rs['email'];
          $date_joined = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($rs["join_date"]));
     }
     $encode_id = base64_encode("encodeuserid{$id}");
}
```

My aim is to catch fields from mySQL such as `email`, `username`, `join_date`.

Comment: There is no `is` in this question.

Comment: Or in the code @chris85

Comment: There are no PHP syntax errors in this code, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: And note, `"SELECT * FROM * users ...` is probably not what you want.

Comment: Did you start the session? ---- OP: *"Yes... I just didn't include it, and didnt' think it was important"*.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM * users` huh??

Comment: `$_SESSON` < *GROAN!!!* ^ v

Comment: your code's full of errors

Comment: the sessions already implemented so why am i going to include it when its already in there? @Fred-ii-.... the session is contained in session.php and placed at the top of each page.